# Don't allow the customer to login to the account

Tags: magento2, customer-account

How to **disallow** the customer to login ? 
for example:

> when a custom attribute is set to false

Comment: `a custom attribute` does this attribute belong to the customer entity or not?

Comment: belong to the customer entity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

magento Perform customer logic authorization from `authenticate()` method of  `Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement`.

If i you want to prevent a customer from login basic of some condition then you can use this function.

Create around method on it and basic of throw the `UserLockedException`  or `EmailNotConfirmedException` type error.

**Plugin class:**

```
<?php


namespace {Vendorname}\{ModuleName}\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;

class AccountManagement {
     /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
     CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) 
    {
      $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;  
    }
    public function aroundAuthenticate(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $username,
        $password
       )
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->get($username);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }  

        $CustomerfieldValue= $customer->getCustomAttribute('{Attribute_Code}')
            ? $customer->getCustomAttribute('{Attribute_Code}')->getValue()
            :false;

        // Condition match throw error for prevent log
        if($CustomerfieldValue == true)
        {
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Access is locked'));
            // access prevent
            // throw new EmailNotConfirmedException(__('Access is locked'));
        }
        // Call original Method

        return $proceed($username,$password);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is should be  `CustomerRepository`. NOT registry.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to vendor\module\Plugin\AccountManagement::aroundAuthenticate() must be an instance of Clousure, instance of Closure given, called in vendor\module\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php on line 135 and defined in.....

Comment: can you help me fix this error ?

Comment: sure.let me check

Comment: Typo mistake `Closure` instead of `Clousure`

Comment: sorry, this was my mistake, it's work for me thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

You can perform your customisation over the `execute` method of `LoginPost` controller in `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost`. Create a preference of this file and perform the needed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
 Create the after plugin for  `isLocked` function, return the result based on custom customer attribute. By this way, default Magento validating the customer before login.

> vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\Authentication.php